# Can't redirect to home page after logging in Vercel prod

Tags: next.js, vercel

Backend: Django REST

Frontend: Nextjs, RTK Query

middlware.ts

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'

const authenticatedUrls = [
  '/current-todo',
  '/create-todo',
  '/completed-todo',
  '/',
]
const unauthenticatedUrls = ['/login', '/signup']

export function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const { pathname } = req.nextUrl
  const authToken = req.cookies.get('token')?.value

  if (authToken) {
    if (unauthenticatedUrls.some((url) => pathname.endsWith(url))) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/', req.url))
    }
  }

  if (!authToken) {
    if (authenticatedUrls.some((url) => pathname.endsWith(url))) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', req.url))
    }
  }
}

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    /*
     * Match all request paths except for the ones starting with:
     * - api (API routes)
     * - _next/static (static files)
     * - _next/image (image optimization files)
     * - favicon.ico (favicon file)
     */
    '/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)',
  ],
}
```

login.tsx

```
  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<FormInputs> = async (inputs) => {
    setIsLoading(true)

    try {
      const { token } = await authLogin(inputs).unwrap()
      Cookies.set('token', token, { sameSite: 'Strict' })

      router.push('/')
    } catch (error: any) {
      dispatch(
        showToast({
          isShow: true,
          text: 'Unable to log in with provided credentials',
          icon: 'error',
        })
      )
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false)
    }
  }
```

Currently its working on my [local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDyvB.gif)

but not working in Vercel [prod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Xuqc.gif)

Edit: It only happened on the first visit in prod

Does the middleware work differently in local and prod? Is there anything need to be configure?

I'm expecting to work just fine in vercel just like in the local.